# Fused Location provider providing "accurate" locations but reporting very bad accuracy values

Tags: android, location, android-fusedlocation

I'm developing an Android location tracking APP. My problem is, although the fused location provider providing locations that are accurate to 10,20,30 meters (I can verify that by looking at a map and the latitude, longitude and timestamp values), those locations report accuracy values that sometimes reach 600-800 meters.

I understand that the fused location provider uses multiple sensors to determine the user location, saving energy and providing location estimates that would otherwise be impossible to obtain using GPS only.

This way it's really hard to define an accuracy threshold to filter noisy locations. I started by using an accuracy threshold of 50 meters when the user is still (no ongoing trip), and 200 meters when an ongoing trip is acknowledged. I'm missing a lot of trips since a lot of locations are filtered out...but after looking at the raw values on the map, they are much more accurate than the accuracy value reported.

Any thoughts? Thanks very much in advance!

edit: 10 seconds between samples when on a trip, 20 seconds between samples when still

Comment: Just a thought: have you tried playing around with LocationRequest and, for example, using the flag called PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @Dogcat ! Yes -         mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);